# Hiding specific column in search results

Tags: search, search-results, column

How do I hide specific column when user search for an item?

For example, user searches for other people's names and the personal detail comes out but some detail should be hidden such as email.

Is there a way to customize the search results to hide certain columns for all users?

Comment: While this can be done "visually", savvy users can easily find content from the index that is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the SharePoint is 2013.

This can be achieved by creating a new Result Type and Search Display Template.

1. Go to site collection's Site Settings -> Web Designer Galleries -> Master pages and page layouts -> Display Templates -> Search and download `Item_Person.html`.
2. Open `Item_Person.html` and find `var has_email`. Set its value to `false`. Edit the title tag `<title>Custom People Item</title>` Save the file with a new name `Custom_Item_Person.html` and upload back to SharePoint at the same location. After few seconds SharePoint will create the corresponding `Custom_Item_Person.js`.
3. Go to the search page and edit the `People Search Core Results` web part and click on `result types` under `Display Templates`.

[image]

4. Create a copy of the `Person` result type.

[image]

5. Give it a new name. Select the `Custom People Item` in the dropdown `What should these results look like?` and save.
6. Edit the search page again and edit `People Search Core Results` web part. This time it should display `Custom People Item` in the result type dropdown.
7. Test the search and it should hide the email.

Hope that helps!